# Only float value with dot (not comma) in input - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like have always only float value with dot (not comma) in my inputs.

```
<input type="text" class="dot"> <br />
<input type="text" class="dot"> <br />
<input type="text" class="dot"> <br />

$('.dot').keydown(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val().toString().replace(/\,/g, '.'));  
})
```

this replace comma to dot, but this should not be have > 1 dot and others... This should be accept only [0-9] and .

if i type a different value than other [0-9] and . then this value should be remove - ''.

How can i make it?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkBW/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/9Ry9t/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkBW/2/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/HJnLD/

Bit different from your solution but if you keen to use this, it will not allow any `characters` to type in the text box.

The solution does full validation for numbers and for float it will not take (dot)

**code sample**

```
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which < 46
    || event.which > 59) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } // prevent if not number/dot

    if(event.which == 46
    && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } // prevent if already dot
});​
```

Comment: this is perfect, but i have on problem  - i can't use BACKSPACE and DELETE :)

Comment: Hiya @TonyEvyght just to confirm man you do not want backspace and delete to work in the text box right? because they are working at the moment, cheers!

Comment: in Firefox doesnt working, but in chrome working... In Opera also not work

Comment: @TonyEvyght Hmm weird tried in safari it works! :) hmm can you do me a favor run this and see what alert do you get for delete and backspace key: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkBW/9/ delete should be 8, Don't panic if dot doesn't work as I have changed the event from `key press` to `keydown` just to test why it is not working in the browser you mentioned. hope this helps, cheerios!

Comment: thanks, i accept answer (i can't add +1). could you add delete and backspace to this example so that it was correctly?

Comment: Lol @TonyEvyght I made few more changes gimme 2 more mins bruv, back in a sec! see yous!

Comment: @TonyEvyght almost there testing it now, I have changed the event hence few other things are changed!

Comment: @TonyEvyght and done see here http://jsfiddle.net/HJnLD/ : event changed `keyDown` now and `dlete = 8, . = 190 & backspace is 46` handled accordingly rest code should be clear, take care, cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit Hi. And in case if i input some value in textBox, save it some where (for example in db) and now after page-refresh i load this value again in textbox - why i can input any symbol after all?.

Comment: @user2167382 not sure what your question is but; *if I understand it correctly*if you are storing the value in db and reading in every page refresh depends on the operation and the data integrity, i.e. consider page-cycle and what that data is doing etc... also if its jsut a input box AJAX it and dont page refresh. `:)` hope this helps.

Comment: THE BEST !, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really terrible if statement to circumvent the fact that `parseFloat` can parse the first number it finds in a string and `indexOf` only returns the first index of a character (not all indexes).

It would probably be smarter to store the value of `$(this).val()` in a variable but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. (don't have time right now)

```
if(!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()) && $(this).val().indexOf(".") > -1 && $(this).val().indexOf(".") == $(this).val().lastIndexOf(".")) { 
    // do something, your value is a valid float
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

[http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkBW/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkBW/20/)

```js
var parseInput = function(val) {
  var floatValue = parseFloat(val);
  return isNaN(floatValue) ? '' : floatValue;
}

$('.number').keyup(function(){
  var value = $(this).val()+'';
  if (value[value.length-1] !== '.') {
    $(this).val(parseInput(value));
  }
}).focusout(function(){
  $(this).val(parseInput($(this).val()+''));
})
```

I used keyup to avoid displaying the character if invalid.
As mentionned in comments, I also used focusout.
I do not parse if the last entered character is '.' because you will not be able to enter a decimal value.

Comment: thanks, this is perfect, but i can type many dot (...) and click outside input - then many dot are still

Comment: Ok, I made some changes to valid also on focusout(): look at the JsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkBW/20/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dot').keydown(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().toString().replace(/^[0-9]\./g, ',')
    .replace(/\./g, ''));
})​
```

[How it behave](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkBW/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to do
but how about this

```
$(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0);
```

Comment: This won't work because there could be more than one dot and this would still return a valid number. It would simply parse up to the second dot and take everything before it and convert that bit to a number.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - needed a text input to accept only an integer or a decimal input (only one .) 
Had to mix a few solutions, but this is working now:

```
$(".dot").keyup(function(event){
    this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');
    var parts=this.value.split(".");
    var decimal=false;
    for(var part in parts)
    {
        if(part==0) this.value=parts[part];
        if(part==1) this.value=this.value+"."+parts[part];
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$("#txtSellerPrice").keydown(function (e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 110 && this.value.split('.').length == 2) 
    { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    } 
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190,110]) !== -1 ||         (e.keyCode == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true ) ) ||                   (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {  return;  } if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) 
    { e.preventDefault(); } 
    });
```