# restrict user to input only two digit after decimal

Tags: javascript

I want user to restrict user that they can only enter two digit after decimal.
but they can also remove the entered digits using space key. I have following code but its not allowing me to remove the entered digits using space Like:

Suppose I have entered : 5454645.54 now if user will move cursoe on text box and want to remove these digits its not allowing user to do so. Please advice which correction need to do for this in following code:

```
function restrictUser(el, evt) {  
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    var number = el.value.split('.');
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))     {
        return false;
    }

    if(number.length>1 && charCode == 46){
         return false;
    }
    var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
    var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");
    if( caratPos > dotPos && dotPos>-1 && (number[1].length > 1)){
        return false;
    }
     return true;
}
function getSelectionStart(o) {
    if (o.createTextRange) {
        var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
        r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
        if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
        return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
    } else return o.selectionStart
}
```

Thanks Advance.

Comment: Actually it was not allowing to add tag as Javascript. Can you please advice

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680506/how-to-prevent-keypress-two-digits-after-a-decimal-number

Comment: in that code there is already bug. it also do not allow user to remove entered text using space..